# Angular production build with index.jsp instead of index.html

Tags: node.js, angular

I want want to create an index.jsp file instead of index.html while doing production build.  This weird requirement is for capturing the header part which we will getting from other Oracle Authentication Manager so I want load my appliation from index.jsp.  My index.jsp should look something like this

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" session="true" %>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CardEncryption</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css"></head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.9a8743e2009b1e7b1fbd.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.dcf4ad6dff6130812df3.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

Any suggestion to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you only want the `index.jsp` when doing the production build. The development process should still use `index.html`

In that case you should

1. Create a `index.jsp` file in the same directory as your `index.html` file (so you have both).
2. Update your `angular.json` file's production configuration by adding an index property to your production configuration like this:

[image]

That will make sure that it uses `index.jsp` when you build with `--prod`, but still uses `index.html` for development.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, is that possible to create this index.jsp instead of index.html while doing prod build.  Coz currently I'm doing manually copy pasting the index.html file into the index.jsp file.